# Change the 'Loading' state from another reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have an `authReducer` with  and the User state.
I also have a `generalReducer` with state relating to error notification message and loading true/false.

How do I, when loading the login or another task in a seperate reducer, modify or make a global `loading` state variable from one reducer that is relating to another reducer?

**generalReducer.js**:

```
let defaultState = {
    loading: false,
    error: null,
    notification: false,      
};

export default function generalReducer(state = defaultState, action){
switch(action.type){
    case loading:
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: action.payload.isLoading,
        };
     default:
        return state;
     }
```

**authReducer.js**

```
let defaultState = {
    user: {
        displayName: null,
        email: null,
        photoUrl: null,
        isAnonymous: null,
        phone: null,
    }
};

export default function authReducer(state = defaultState, action){
    switch(action.type){
    case LOGIN_BEGIN:
    case LOGOUT_BEGIN:
        return {
            ...state,
        };
    case LOGIN_FAILURE:
    case LOGOUT_FAILURE:
        return {
            ...state,
    };
    case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
    return {
        ...state,
        user: action.payload.user
    };
    default:
    return state;
    }
}
```

In `authReducer.js` i want to be able to set the `loading` or `error` state in `generalReducer` to correspond to the error or loading state required. How?

Comment: post some relevant code with representing issue.

Comment: Please find the edits adding in auth and general reducers

Comment: you can take a look at redux-saga https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga

Answer (score 0):

You need to import authActionTypes from authActions and update the reducer in generalReducer.js

**generalReducer.js:**

```
import {
  LOGIN_BEGIN,
  LOGOUT_BEGIN,
  LOGIN_FAILURE,
  LOGOUT_FAILURE,
  LOGIN_SUCCESS,
} from './authActions;

let defaultState = {
    loading: false,
    error: null,
    notification: false,      
};

export default function generalReducer(state = defaultState, action){
switch(action.type){
    case loading:
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: action.payload.isLoading,
        };
    case LOGIN_BEGIN:
    case LOGOUT_BEGIN: {
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
        error: null,
      }
    }
    case LOGIN_FAILURE:
    case LOGOUT_FAILURE: {
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        error: 'Set Your Error Here',
      }
    }
    case LOGIN_SUCCESS: {
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        error: null,
      }
    }
     default:
        return state;
     }
```

Hope this helps.